# StfalconImageViewer keeping track of current image being viewed

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am trying to use this 'StfalconImageViewer' in my gallery app. I have managed to get it working to view image from the grid. But facing problems when trying to share the current image. If I click on an image to open it with StfalconImageViewer and then share that image it works fine but if I swipe left or right to view another image (rather than going back to grid view and clicking on another to view) and then click on the share button, then it share the first image that I clicked on in grid to view. Which make sense as in code I have reference to the first image that I clicked on to open with StfalconImageViewer.

There is "withImageChangeListener" in library but couldn't find any example of it. I downloaded its sample app from repo but couldn't really understand it. If someone could explain how to use that to solve this problem that would be good.

my code structure is like

```
MainActivity {
   RecycledGrid {
     GridAdapater
  }
}

//------------separate file ---------------
GridAdapter {

 onBindViewHolder (holder, position) {
     view = getCustomOVerlayView();
     shareBtn = getShareButtonFromView();
     shareBtn.Onclick() {
          share(images[position];
      }
     new StfalconImageViewer.Builder<>(context, images, ... )
                  .withStartPosition(position)
                  .withOverlayView(view)
                  .show();
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide full code of your implementation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libray provides an imageChangeListener:

```
.withImageChangeListener(new OnImageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onImageChange(int position) {
        Log.i(TAG, "position" + position);
    }
})
```